# Android not saving sharedPrefs

Tags: android

So I'm just trying to save a string.. But everytime I rerun the app, I get null for the saved String :/ I'm 100% sure I'm calling the save method, and that the string it not null when I'm saving it.

```
public class CFUser {

private final static String ID_KEY="myUserID";
private static String userID;

public static String getUserID(Context context) {
    if(userID==null) {
        SharedPreferences prefs= context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(ID_KEY, 0);
        userID=prefs.getString(ID_KEY, null);
        }

    return userID;
}
public static void setUserID(String id, Context context) {
    userID=id;
    Log.d("saving", id);
    SharedPreferences prefs=context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(ID_KEY, 0);
    prefs.edit().putString(ID_KEY, userID);
    prefs.edit().apply();
}
public static boolean isLoggedIn(Context context) {
    return getUserID(context)!=null;
}
```

}

many thanks!

Comment: do     `editor.commit();`

Comment: @MD: `commit()` works the same as `apply()`, with the difference that `apply()` is asynchronous (and therefore recommended in this case).

Comment: @TobiasBaumeister Completely agree!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code, you are creating two different `SharedPreferences.Editor` Objects:

```
SharedPreferences prefs=context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(ID_KEY, 0);
prefs.edit().putString(ID_KEY, userID);
prefs.edit().apply();
```

So that means you are putting the String in `Editor1`, but are committing the (non-existant) changes of `Editor2`.
You need to do it this way:

```
SharedPreferences prefs=context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(ID_KEY, 0);
SharedPreferenced.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.putString(ID_KEY, userID);
edit.apply();
```

Comment: hmmm you got it!!! +1 up

Comment: And I've read atleast 3 threads about this, and wasn't even thinking I'm doing such a silly mistake. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the name of your entire `SharedPreferences` file is `myUserID` because of how you're retrieving the SharedPreferences. Instead use the following. This isn't causing the issue but I'm assuming you don't want the `SharedPreferences` file as your ID key...

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Then when you're writing to the preferences make sure you're using the same `Editor`.

```
Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString(ID_KEY,userID);
editor.apply();
```